# DocuSign REST API - Retrieve partially signed document

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using REST API for Embedded Signing. I need to obtain the signed document when the first signer (of N) signed. When creating the envelope, I'm sending the recipientEvents array as follows:

```
"recipientEvents": [

    {
      "includeDocuments": "true",
      "recipientEventStatusCode": "completed"
    }
]
```

In my endpoint I'm receiving a base encoded document in the XML response (see below) for the RecipientStatus with status completed. However this is not the document signed by the first signee but the original one sent along with the create envelope json. How can I receive the signed document from DS?

```
  <DocumentPDFs>
      <DocumentPDF>
         <Name>Test2.pdf</Name>
         <PDFBytes>JVBERi0xLjQKJfv8/f4KJVdyaXRpbmcgb2JqZWN0cy4uLgoxNCAwIG9i ---</PDFBytes>
         <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
         <DocumentType>CONTENT</DocumentType>
      </DocumentPDF>
   </DocumentPDFs>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make a REST API call for the document from you server in this case because it's a recipient event and the entire envelope is not complete yet. This is what it looks like:

```
GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{ACCOUNT_ID}/envelopes/{ENVELOPE_ID}/documents/{DOCUMENT_ID}
```

Comment: The PDF you retrieve should be generated on download as the most up-to-date version of the envelope. As signers complete their portions, more data will become visible. If you'd like for data you submit in tabs to be present right away, you can reach out to DocuSign support and have them enable the 'Display Securefield Initial Value' setting. If you're seeing something else on your side, I'd recommend opening a case so we can have a closer look at what's going on.

Comment: @silvana please mark this as resolved or let us know if you need additional help